# extjs6 adjust grid row height

Tags: css, extjs

I am trying to change the height on the rows in my extjs grid.  Trying to understand the different ways to accomplish this reading the theming guide in the extjs6 docs.
From what I understand the most common way to do this is create a cls:.
I've attempted using a fiddle example but doesn't seem to do anything at all.

```
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store,
    cls: 'custom-grid',
    columns: [
        {text: "Name", width:120, dataIndex: 'Name'},
        {text: "DOB", width: 120, dataIndex: 'dob', renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('M d, Y'), },
        {text: "Age", width:40, 
            renderer : function(value, metaData, record, rowIdx, colIdx, store, view){
                return calcAge(record.get('dob'));
            }
        }

    ],
    renderTo:'example-grid',
    width: 320,
    height: 280,
    viewConfig: { 
        stripeRows: false, 
        getRowClass: function(record) { 
            return calcAge(record.get('dob')) < 18 ? 'minor' : 'adult'; 
        } 
    } 
});
```

});

below is my css I am trying to use

```
.custom-grid .x-grid-row-table TD {
line-height: 4px;
}

.custom-grid .x-grid-row { 
height: 25px;
}
```

--- BELOW AREA SEEMS TO WORK NOW ----

This seems to work in fiddle but I do not know where to put the css in my file structure

```
.custom-grid .x-grid-row {
background: red;
line-height: 1px;
}
```

The panel that contains the grids is located in 
app/view/clientdetails/clientdetails.js
so I tried to put the css code in 
app/packages/local/my-classic-theme2/sass/src/view/clientdetails/clientdetails.scss

Answer (score 1):

I've made a Fiddle (https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1cd6) based on your snippet which shows how to customise the row height based on the CSS class added via the `getRowClass` method.

The CSS is very simple:

```
.custom-grid .minor {
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
}

.custom-grid .adult {
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: sorry, my example wasn't exactly clear.  I copied it from somewhere else.  I want to affect all rows equally.  That being said I looked at your fiddle and changed the height number... it can get bigger, but there seems to be a minimum size... like I cannot make it very very small.  is that the case?

Comment: I think I got it in your fiddle using .custom-grid .x-grid-row {
    background: red;
    line-height: 1px;
}

Comment: last issue, now I am trying to put this in my application and the change is not being reflected.  I think because I do not understand where to actually put the custom css.  can you tell me where in my file hierarchy its supposed to go?  I edited post to show my paths

Comment: Because that SCSS file doesn't relate to a class (a theme only knows about Ext files) it will need to go in your application's sass folder in the same path as you have it now. I like to think as styling that belongs in the theme should be Ext components (i.e. you would transfer to another app), and any app components should be styled in the app itself.